# What is the composition of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want to write a proof to show that the composition of two functions is a function. To do that, I need to define the composition of two functions, but I haven't been able to verify my attempt. Here it is.

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be well-defined functions, and let $f \circ g : X \rightarrow Z$ be the composition of $g$ to $f$. The composition $f \circ g$ is defined as

$$f \circ g := \{(x, z) : \exists y \ni (x, y) \in f \, \mathrm{and} \, (y, z) \in g\}$$

Please I'd like to know it this definition is correct, and if not, the correct definition. Thanks.

Comment: See [Composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Definition).

Comment: Thanks for the link @MauroALLEGRANZA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you understand the meaning of composite functions, and that you're interested in the explicit definition.
In that case, to define it formally it is best to understand that when composing the functions, although $g$ acts on $Y$, the composition of $g$ on $f$ acts on $Image(f) = Im(f) := \{f(x) | x\in X\} \subseteq Y$.

So the composite consists of all the copules $(x,z)$ such that x is sent by f to some image $y=f(x)$ and $g$'s action on that image results in $z = g(y)$.

> $ g∘f:=\{(x,z) |\ \exists y \in Y : f(x) = y \land g(y) = z  \}$

Comment: Oh I see. So my definition above was for $g \circ f$?

Comment: Yes :)
That is why I emphasised the intuition from which the formal definition is derived.

Comment: So if I were to write the reverse, I wouldn't be able to use the same domain and range as I used in the post?

Comment: In your post you stated that  $f:X \rightarrow Y$  and $ g: Y \rightarrow Z$, so the only logical composition is of g on f, since f cannot be composed on g (if X is not equal to Z).

Comment: I see. So would this be a better representation? Let $f:X_{1} \rightarrow Y_{1}$ and $g:X_{2} \rightarrow Y_{2}$ be arbitrary and well-defined. Then $f \circ g := \{(x, z) : \exists y \ni (x, y) \in g \, \mathrm{and} \, (y, z) \in f\}$

Comment: Actually no, because it is crucial that the image of the function $f$ would be in the origin of the function $g$.
We can take the following example:
$f: N \rightarrow \{ even \ naturals\}$ and $g: \{even \ naturals\} \rightarrow N$ by setting: 
$f(n) = 2n, g(2k) = k$.
Note that if you switch the order then the composite isn't correctly defined.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thanks. Let me see what I can do.